# Wordpress picks a wrong template if ?cat= is used as URL parameter

Tags: url-rewriting, rewrite-rules

I have a website with the following article structure. This works and uses archive.php template like it's supposed to

*website.com/category/articles/arrester/?tag=online-lectures*

This also works and uses tag-online-lectures.php like it's supposed to

*website.com/tag/online-lectures/*

Now, THIS doesn't work - it works in a sense that it displays all articles with a tag "online lectures" and only articles with this tag in the category with id 7, **however** it uses archive.php template and not tag-online-lectures.php like I thought it would.

*website.com/tag/online-lectures/?cat=7*

Why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why?

This is because the pretty permalink:

```
/tag/online-lectures/?cat=7
```

gets translated to the ugly permalink:

```
index.php?tag=online-lectures&cat=7
```

And as you can see the `/tag/online-lectures` part no longer has the emphasis it once had. Afterall `/category/arrester?tag=online-lectures` would boil down to exactly the same ugly URL.

Since the resulting query is an archive, and the most specific template available is `archive.php` it chooses that template.

Remember, it's not the URL that determines which template gets loaded, it's the main query. The URL is converted from /pretty/style/permalinks to `index.php?ugly=style`, which is then used to create the query parameters, which get put into the main query, which fetches the posts. After that WP uses the main query object to run through the template hierarchy and pick a template to load.

#### Changing The Template

Your assumption may have been incorrect, but that doesn't mean you can't use the template you expected. It just means you need a filter to identify this situation and load a different template instead using `template_include`.

For example, here we request `natalia.php` from the theme if we put `?natalia=1` in the URL:

```php
add_filter( 'template_include', 'natalia_template' );

function natalia_template( $template ) {
    if ( isset( $_GET['natalia` ) ) {
        return 'natalia.php';
    }
    return $template;
}
```

You can use a similar filter to inspect the query variables and choose the template you prefer.

Comment: thank you, this is clear

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the `tag-online-lectures.php` template for all tag archives within a specific category, regardless of the category ID, you can modify your tag.php template to check if the current tag archive is within the desired category, and then include the `tag-online-lectures.php` template if it is.

Here's an example of how you could modify your `tag.php` template to achieve this:

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying tag archives
 *
 * @link https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Your_Theme_Name
 * @since 1.0.0
 */

// Get the current tag object
$tag = get_queried_object();

// Get the IDs of all categories that this tag is assigned to
$categories = wp_get_object_terms( $tag->term_id, 'category', array( 'fields' => 'ids' ) );

// Check if the tag is assigned to a category with the desired slug
if ( in_array( 'articles', $categories ) ) {

    // Include the tag-online-lectures.php template
    get_template_part( 'tag-online-lectures' );

} else {

    // Include the default tag.php template
    get_template_part( 'archive', 'tag' );

}
```

Comment: no, sorry, it won't work, I have dozens of categories. The category ID has to be dynamic.